# freeglut error LNK1104

Tags: linker, freeglut

In my project I want to use a freeglut library from the unofficial opengl sdk.

I used Premake to generate build files for vs2010. Then I built all libraries (debug). In my project I set Additional Include Directories, Additional Library Directories for the freeglut. In additional dependencies I added freeglutD.lib.

In the code I just include a freeglut header. When I want to run the program I get an error:

```
>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'freeglut.lib'.
```

The freeglutD.lib is the only file in `sdk/freeglut/lib`. There is no `freeglut.dll` and `freeglut.lib` in sdk.

Earlier I was using freeglut 2.8.0 MSVC Package from [link](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/) which is linked dynamically (contain freeglut.dll) and everything works fine.

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you forgot these lines from the documentation on using the SDK:

> You will also need to add some #defines to your command line. These are:
>
> - FREEGLUT_STATIC
> - _LIB
> - FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS=0

You need that `FREEGLUT_STATIC` to let GLUT know that it's linking statically. Otherwise it looks for a DLL.

Comment: Thanks Jason, `FREEGLUT_STATIC` solved my linker errors; additionally I also had to give `-lgdi32` and `-lwinmm` which seem to be required for statically linking FreeGLUT in a MinGW setup (http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/).

Answer (score 0):

I had an older project from VS12 and got the same LNK1104 error when trying to build it after upgrade in VS15. All I had to do to fix this was run Package Manager Console (Tools - NuGet Package Manager) and type in:

```
Install-Package freeglut
```

Note, that I have reference to glew.h and freeglut.h in one of my header files like this:

```
#include "..\packages\nupengl.core.0.1.0.1\build\native\include\GL\glew.h" 
#include "..\packages\nupengl.core.0.1.0.1\build\native\include\GL\freeglut.h"
```