# Why is Visual Studio Trying to Link 'freeglutd.lib'?

Tags: visual-studio, freeglut

I'm trying to compile an OpenGL program using Visual Studio 2013, but I get the following error:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'freeglutd.lib'   ...

For reference, I have FreeGLUT installed and have configured VS to search the correct directories for the include files and library files. Indeed, VS recognises the GLUT include files just fine. I've also added *opengl32.lib* and *freeglut.lib* to the *Additional Dependencies*.

Why is VS looking for 'freeglutd.lib'? It's definitely not listed in the Additional Dependencies. I can solve the compilation error by renaming 'libglut.lib' to 'libglutd.lib' and removing the former from the dependencies, but I'm just curious why it's behaving this way.

Speaking of Additional Dependencies, is adding opengl32.lib actually necessary? I can compile my (very basic) program without it, but more than one person has said it's required, perhaps for older versions of Visual Studio?

Comment: Try doing a solution-wide search for `libglutd.lib`, and see what emerges.  I suspect that one of your project XML files is slightly corrupted.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I searched the entire solution for `libglutd.lib` and `freeglutd.lib` (I guess that's what you meant) but nothing was found. Edit: I checked the log file as well, and the link command doesn't have 'freeglutd.lib' as a library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you check the freeglut_std.h (freeglut V3.0):

```
            /* Link with Win32 shared freeglut lib */
#           if FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS
#               ifdef NDEBUG
#                   pragma comment (lib, "freeglut.lib")
#               else
#                   pragma comment (lib, "freeglutd.lib")
#               endif
#           endif
```

so if you don't define NDEBUG, the linker will link to "freeglutd.lib",
you can solve that by defining a NDEBUG in "PreprocessorDefinitions".
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Hey man I don't know if you're still having this error but here is a solution. Pretty much the "freeglutd.lib" has to do with debugging, hence the "d" on the end, so what I did was go into the:

**Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions** and type NDEBUG.  Then **OK** and **Apply**.

What this does is in the "freeglut_std.h" there is a ifdef for NDEBUG that if it is defined then use "freeglut.lib" otherwise it's going to use the "freeglutd.lib". So by defining it in the Preprocessor Definitions, you are now using the "freeglut.lib". Hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your answer.
Codes within sentences are to be formatted as `code` 
Very Important words to be **bold** , less important onces *Italic*

Answer (score 1):

Possibly already answered: [freeglut error LNK1104](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954344/freeglut-error-lnk1104)

Also two things to check for:

- Are you building in debug or release mode? The **d** at the end of freeglutd.lib suggests that it's a library meant for debug builds
- Try creating a new project from scratch, put some basic runnable code in it that uses freeGLUT and see if VS is linking properly. This will also verify if for some reason the project file of the previous project was corrupted (as @RobertHarvey suggested) or the problem is somewhere else

Comment: I looked at that answer before and it didn't help unfortunately. I tried both debug and release mode. I also did as you suggested and created a new project, but no luck.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Btw I just so the end of your question - yes, opengl is needed as a dependency because freeGLUT uses OpenGL but covers some of its complexity (window creation, input event handling, initialisation of OpenGL stuff etc. Can you post a screen shot of your project settings (linking dependencies, headers etc.). OpenGL does not require freeGLUT but I have the feeling that you are writing OpenGL code from somewhere, where freeGLUT is used instead of pure OpenGL hence the dependency on freeGLUT.

Comment: I just realised I wasn't applying the suggestion from the linked answer properly. I defined those macros *after* including `GL/glut.h`, which is pointless. I can now say the problem is with `FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS` being equal to 1. More specifically, if it is equal to 1, `GL/freeglut_std.h` will try to link `libglutd.lib` if `NDEBUG` is not defined. So it is meant for debug builds, but Release mode doesn't define NDEBUG by default. PS upon inspection of the glut header file, `opengl32.lib` is linked for you if `FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS` is 1.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by compiling freeglut and freeglut_static from generated CMake soluton in Debug mode - freeglutd was created in the lib/Debug directory. You can put this directory into lib path then and it will work!