# Visual C++ with OpenGL: Failing to use GLUT

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, glut, freeglut

I am trying to run a C project in Visual Studio 2013, with GLUT.

After some readings over the web, I tried with **freeglut**, but I get the following error when trying to run my project:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'freeglutd.lib'
```

Can anyone explain how to use GLUT in Visual Studio?

Comment: [this is my answer, hope to help][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32845763/5363594

Answer (score 1):

Goto  Configuration Properties>Linker>Input

Add freeglutd.lib in Additional Dependencies 
Thats it!
Make sure you are using same calling conversion, which used to built the lib. i.e  either stdcall or cdecl.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself:

Finally succeeded doing it using the following awesome guide:

http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/glut-howto/#win