# defining pragmas in a freeglut programme

Tags: c++, pragma, freeglut

I am building an application that uses freeglut, in windows 32bit, debug mode. I have linked the static debug freeglut lib.

To fix linkage errors, as mentioned here:

[freeglut error LNK1104](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954344/freeglut-error-lnk1104)

I have added:

```
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#define _LIB
#define FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS = 1
```

to the head of my .cpp.

That solves the linkage errors, but gives me an error in the freeglut_std.h file.

These sections:

```
    #       if FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS
#          pragma comment (lib, "freeglut_static.lib")
#       endif

#   if FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS
#       pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")    /* link OpenGL Utility lib     */
#       pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib") /* link Microsoft OpenGL lib   */
#       pragma comment (lib, "gdi32.lib")    /* link Windows GDI lib        */
#       pragma comment (lib, "winmm.lib")    /* link Windows MultiMedia lib */
#       pragma comment (lib, "user32.lib")   /* link Windows user lib       */
#   endif
```

give me:

```
Error   3   error C1017: invalid integer constant expression    freeglut_std.h  72  1   

4   IntelliSense: expected an expression    freeglut_std.h  72  12
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: don't you mean `#define FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS 1` ?

Comment: ah, I do. thanks! My linkage errors have come straight back though.  aaargh.