# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'freeglut.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, freeglut

using visual studio 2015

already added in
Linker -> General -> Addtional Library Dependencies
and
Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Still recieving `error LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'freeglut.lib'`

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Recently had the same issue trying to run 64bit. In addition to the usual linker settings, following solved my issue;

add following

```
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#define _LIB
#define FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS 0
```

Before your include

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
```

As per [freeglut error LNK1104](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954344/freeglut-error-lnk1104)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, suppose you are using ***VS Studio***. In that case, you can download the nupengl core package by right-clicking your project folder in the ***Solution Explorer*** and selecting the option ***Manage Nuget Packages...***.
[Right-Click on Project in Solution Explorer and Find Manage Nuget Packages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwXdL.png)

A new tab will be added, search for ***nupengl*** and install. After doing this, you can change the ***Active solution platform:*** to x64. The Active solution platform is the option next to Debug where it shows the options: x64, x86, ARM64. [Search for nupengl and install.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61ULg.png)
[Change Active Solution Platform to x64.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9hWd.png)

and then including in your cpp file:
#include <GL/glut.h>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

its bringing Static linking is not supported with this build. Please remove the FREEGLUT_STATIC preprocessor directive, or download the source code from http://freeglut.sf.net/ and build against that. for vc2010